# Mongodb morphia complex query

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I want to do this query in Java with Morphia Driver for Mongo DB, this how i do in mongo shell (and works)

**db.prova.find({"username":"prova", "roles":"user"})**

Comment: There's a tutorial [**Using Morphia to map Java objects in MongoDB**](http://city81.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/using-morphia-to-map-java-objects-in.html) that could be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/getting-started/quick-tour/).  There's a number of examples and reference material to get you started.

*(The tutorial in the comment above is really old and no longer matches the current Morphia releases, for what it's worth.)*